# Sphinx search in django admin

Tags: django, django-admin, sphinx, django-sphinx

Trying to use sphinx search in django admin. Installed [django-sphinx](https://github.com/dcramer/django-sphinx).

Did as Docs tell:

```
from djangosphinx.admin import SphinxModelAdmin

class MyAdmin(SphinxModelAdmin):
        index = 'my_index_name' # defaults to Model._meta.db_table
        weights = {'field': 100}
```

As result I got error `global name 'Paginator' is not defined`, fixed it, then another one `'list' object has no attribute 'ordered'`

Don't know what to do with this.

P.S. Django 1.3 if it matters.

Comment: What happens with your index when you define (and search against) that index in a `djangosphinx.SphinxSearch()` call?

Answer (score 0):

I think may the django version is not satisfied,now the django version is 
[django 1.6.2](https://www.djangoproject.com/download/),or you can use [xadmin](https://github.com/sshwsfc/django-xadmin) ,
which is good

At last,I think it is the django version,I suggest you should update the latest!